# LUA read file from specific line to specific line

Tags: file, lua

i try to make lua script read file

data.txt

```
1626363 NameA LastNameB
42342344 NameC LastNameD
345345 NameE LastNameF
87978987 NameG LastName
1626363 NameA LastNameB
42342344 NameC LastNameD
345345 NameE LastNameF
87978987 NameG LastNameH
```

*this all data not same id and person

what i want try to do is :

example:
value A = <1 byte data to 60>

```
1626363 NameA LastNameB
42342344 NameC LastNameD
345345 N
```

so row 3 is not complete data, so i want data row 1 and 2 and skip row 3

```
1626363 NameA LastNameB
42342344 NameC LastNameD
```

value B will start with row 3 until end

```
345345 NameE LastNameF
87978987 NameG LastName
1626363 NameA LastNameB
42342344 NameC LastNameD
345345 NameE LastNameF
87978987 NameG LastNameH
```

every value maximum 60 byte,

sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: You don't explain what you want your script to actually do. What should the output be?

Comment: What is your definition of "complete data"?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want. But answer for question `read file from specific line to specific line` is

```
local function skip_n_lines(f, n)
  while f:read('*l') do
    n = n - 1
    if n == 0 then break end
  end
  return n
end

local function read_n_lines(f, n)
  local t = {}
  for i = 1, n do
    local s = f:read('*l')
    if not s then break end
    t[#t + 1] = s
  end
  return t
end

local f = io.open('test.txt', 'rb+')
if 0 == skip_n_lines(f, 12) then
  local data = read_n_lines(f, 4)
end
```